# Update Quarto in RStudio

Tags: rstudio, quarto

I would like to update `Quarto` inside the terminal of `Rstudio` to v1.3.290. I followed the installation like described [here](https://quarto.org/docs/download/tarball.html?version=1.3.290&idPrefix=download-pre), but I keep getting errors which I am not sure about. I runned the following code in Rstudio terminal:

```
wget https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/releases/download/v1.3.290/quarto-1.3.290-linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

and:

```
mkdir ~/opt
tar -C ~/opt -xvzf quarto-1.3.290-linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

So downloading and install works, but creating a symlink like this doesn't work:

```
mkdir ~/bin
ln -s ~/opt/quarto-1.3.290/bin/quarto ~/bin/quarto
```

Error:

```
ln -s ~/opt/quarto-1.3.290/bin/quarto ~/bin/quarto
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/quinten/bin’: File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/quinten/bin/quarto': File exists
```

I am not sure how to fix this error. I think it is not possible to overwrite an already installed quarto version. So I was wondering if anyone understands how to fix this error?

---

**Please note:** I am currently using Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should download the right folder [here](https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/). Make sure you are in the right path of the terminal where the downloaded folder is. After that you can use the following command:

`sudo apt install ./quarto-1.3.294-linux-amd64.deb`

This should install the version. Make sure you restart R and Rstudio.